# In java how are lambda expressions are different from regular functions

Tags: java, lambda

I am really thinking hard to understand why java has introduced new concept called `Lambda Expression` in its 8th version.

I mean as far as I understand it is just like a regular function which calculates an expression and returns the value. Is there anything that a lambda expression does beyond this and what exactly happens behind the screen. Please educate me!!!

Thanks in Advance.!!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: *"Is there anything that a lambda expression does beyond this ..."* - Nope.  *" ... what exactly happens behind the screen."* - Look at the bytecodes, using `javap`.  *"Please educate me!"* - That's your job ... or your teachers.

Comment: The other point of course is that Java doesn't have functions, per se.  It has methods.